# Node child_process exec() crashes system

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have a large folder of files, which I walk through and launch a bash shell command on (it has to do with audio analysis). Each of these commands take a long time and my virtual machine's CPU quickly reaches a 100% load and it crashes. Is there a way of controlling the spawning of `child_process`' so it protects the OS from crashing? Maybe like having a limited pool of processes running at given time or something... I hope someone has experience with this, since I find nothing on when googling the problem :D

I hope that question is not too exotic :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of controlling the spawning of child_process' so it protects the OS from crashing?

Yes, there is.  You would either use some sort of pre-built queuing system or job management system where you pre-configure how many processes you want working on these various jobs at once or you build your own.

As with all questions here on stackoverflow, you would get an answer that is a lot more specific to your particular situation if you include your actual code you have now.  But, the general concept is that you create a work queue.  You decide how many processes you want working at once.  When you add something to the queue, you check to see how many processes are already running.  If the max is already running, then you just add the task to the queue.

If the max number of processes is not yet running, you create a new process, pass it the oldest item from the queue and increment a counter that keeps track of how many child processes (or worker processes) you currently have open.  You monitor each process so that you know when it's done.  Whenever one finishes, you not only process the result, but you also modify the counter for how many processes are running and then if you aren't at the max, you grab the next job in the queue and start up a child process for it.'

The child processes can either run to completion and stop for each job, starting a new one for each new queued item or you can have them communicate back completion, but not terminate and you can send them a new work item.

There are numerous job management or worker management packages like this in npm or you can fairly simply build your own.  I'd personally grab a library that is already written, but the suitability to task of each existing library depends upon your specific implementation details which you have not shared.

Comment: That was actually more than enough! Thank you, I will investigate further and will either use a `npm` package (if I find something that fits my understanding), or just write my own. Thank you so much for the answer!